# jade errors on codepen

Tags: html, pug

I'm trying to make an email template in jade, and I'd like to put it in codepen so other people can have access to it. However, everytime I get an error:

```
CodePen removed the words below from your Jade because they could be used to do bad things. Please remove them and try again. 
->greensborohomevalue
->com <br>
->style <br>
->color <br>
->white <br>
->text <br>
->decoration <br>
->15 <br>
->span <br>
->style <br>
->color <br>
```

every single piece of text... etc

My CodePen can be found here, http://codepen.io/Cutcopy/pen/qdRmOR.

Any idea why it's doing this? It compiled just fine on my desktop.

Comment: It seems codepen doesn't like the site your hyperlinks are pointing to. Otherwise [it works](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVWmdY), and so it isn't Jade error.

Comment: huh. bizarre. It looks like that's the case. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Getting the same thing `CodePen removed the words below from your Jade because they could be used to do bad things. Please remove them and try again. 
->evaluate
->span
->opera
->x`

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving a similar error on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) because my Jade contained the string 'node'.

```
CodePen removed the words below from your Jade because they could be used to do bad things. Please remove them and try again. 
->node
```

My markup included an element with a class called 'ordered-chart-nodes'. Changing the string 'node' to something else (in my case, 'ordered-chart-items'), fixed the error.

Interestingly, such an error happens if using the HTML Jade or Haml preprocessor on Codepen. The string 'node' is allowed to exist regular HTML markup.

Comment: I hypothesize  it might have something to do with code injection security issues, but I have no idea. Ya I never have that issue locally, only on codepen.

Comment: @cutcopy yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!